# Remove blank row from dataset

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

```
  ds.Tables.Add(dt);
  return ds;
```

In the above code snippet, how can i return my dataset but exclude all blank rows i.e blank meaning rows with null or an empty string in all their columns.

Comment: for that checking of null  all the column should be of type string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do that checking before hand and then return the DataTable something like below (an example)

```
for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (dt.Rows[i]["col1"] == DBNull.Value && dt.Rows[i]["col2"] == DBNull.Value)
     {
        dt.Rows[i].Delete();
     }
}
dt.AcceptChanges();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
return ds;
```

Comment: in this case you had assumed table will have only two columns. if table has 500 columns then it would not be efficient to  compare each and every in if statement make it some more lengthy

Comment: you can also don't delte the row in iteration statement

Comment: First of all, did you not read the answer? I said a sample/example .. which will get OP started nicely. Second, check again to confirm whether you can delete row in iteration.

Comment: "Second, check again to confirm whether you can delete row in iteration." Since it's foreach iterating over rows, you obviously cannot. You should get InvalidOperationException.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone stumbles across this article, this is the solution I came up with:

```
// REMOVE ALL EMPTY ROWS
dt_Parsed.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList().FindAll(Row =>
    { return String.IsNullOrEmpty(String.Join("", Row.ItemArray)); }).ForEach(Row =>
        { dt_Parsed.Rows.Remove(Row); });
```

Comment: Or:  `dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList().FindAll(row => string.IsNullOrEmpty(string.Join("", row.ItemArray))).ForEach(row =>
            { dt.Rows.Remove(row); });`

Comment: or:
`dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(w => !w.ItemArray.All(a => a is null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a as string?? a.ToString())))`

Answer (score 0):

Here had helper function in which pass your table that you want to delete datarow with all empty columns(Here I assumed all string are of type string then it will work) 
For other type u can check datacolumn type and then can make relavant checking.

```
 public DataTable DeleteEmptyRows(DataTable dt)
            {
                DataTable formattedTable = dt.Copy();
                List<DataRow> drList = new List<DataRow>();
                foreach (DataRow dr in formattedTable.Rows)
                {
                    int count = dr.ItemArray.Length;
                    int nullcounter=0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < dr.ItemArray.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (dr.ItemArray[i] == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dr.ItemArray[i])))
                        {
                            nullcounter++;
                        }
                    }

                    if (nullcounter == count)
                    {
                        drList.Add(dr);
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < drList.Count; i++)
                {
                    formattedTable.Rows.Remove(drList[i]);
                }
                formattedTable.AcceptChanges();

                return formattedTable;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to loop the DataTables in DataSet with this method:

```
    public void Clear_DataTableEmptyRows(DataTable dataTableControl)
    {

        for (int i = dataTableControl.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            DataRow currentRow = dataTableControl.Rows[i];

            foreach (var colValue in currentRow.ItemArray)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(colValue.ToString()))
                    break;

                dataTableControl.Rows[i].Delete();
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```