# unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Value cannot be null. Parameter name: propName

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, c#-4.0

I am trying to build a database management system for legal department of a company using C# and ASP.net and SQL server

this is the load record method  of the Case.aspx.cs used to load the gridview  of all the cases that we have and its attributes ant i recall it everytime i reload the page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Legal1
{
    public partial class Cases : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                loadrecord();
            }
        }

        protected void loadrecord()
        {
            String connstr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Legal"].ToString();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("AdminViewCases", conn);
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            Gv.DataSource = dt;
            Gv.DataBind();
        }
```

when i run the project and access the cases.aspx through my local host
[the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoHFs.png)

this is the gridview part at my case.aspx file

```
                                  <asp:GridView ID="Gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#FF9900" GridLines="None" Height="269px" >
         <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<Columns>
   
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Serial_Number" HeaderText="Serial_Number" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Judge" HeaderText="Judge" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="Prosecutor" HeaderText="Prosecutor" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="Oponnent" HeaderText="Oponnent" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Last session" HeaderText="Last Session" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Next session" HeaderText="Next session" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="startDate." HeaderText="Start Date" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="Lawyer" HeaderText="Lawyer" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Lawyer_Id" HeaderText="Lawyer_Id" />
    
    
 
 
    </Columns>
         <EditRowStyle BackColor="#FF9900" />
         <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FF9900" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
         <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
         <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FF9900" />
         <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
         <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
         <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
         <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
     </asp:GridView>
```

and this is the stored procedure that execute the view cases part

```
CREATE Proc AdminViewCases

as
begin
Select Serial_Number,Title,Judge,Prosecutor,Oponnent,type,status,[Last session],
[Next session],startDate,Lawyer,Lawyer_Id
from Cases



end
```

i have used the same methodology in other webpages at the project such as view lawyer ,view oponnents ,etc. ant it works properly on all of them. I am new to C# and I have never faced such a problem

Comment: You have the <mysql> tag, but say SQL Server. Which one of those are you using

Comment: I find the root cause of your issue, could you kindly check it. We also could change the values in database if we are using dev environment to verify it. It's better to filter the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated the issue deeper, the root cause we have found, but I still thinking filter the dirty data in DataTable is not a good choice.

The easiest way, we can  add a condition in the stored procedure,.

Like:

```
Select Serial_Number,Title,Judge,Prosecutor,Oponnent,type,status,[Last session],
[Next session],startDate,Lawyer,Lawyer_Id
from Cases
where Lawyer_Id IS NOT NULL
```

---

Null objects in the datasource can cause this problem, so you should filter dirty data.

Useful link: [Remove blank row from dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24925966/7687666)

#### Please check the sample code.

```
        try
        {
            String connstr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Legal"].ToString();
            using (DataTable tempdt = new DataTable())
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        if (query.ToLower().Trim().StartsWith("select"))
                        {
                            comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        }
                        comm.CommandText = query;

                        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(comm))
                        {
                            sda.Fill(tempdt);
                        }
                    }
                }
                // pls set breakpoint here to check the datasource
                // we can remove the null object
                Gv.DataSource = tempdt;
                Gv.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```